# Convex relaxation of an inner product for optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem. The optimization variables are $x \in R^{+,I}$, $y \in {R}^{+,I x S}$ and $z \in {R}^{+,J x S}$. $a_{i}, b_{j}, c_{i}$ and $d_{ij}$ are parameters and all of them are positive. The constraint of the problem is a power cone with $\delta>1$, which can be easily handled with Mosek.

\begin{align}
\min_{x_{i} \geq 0, y_{i,s} \geq 0, z_{j,s} \geq 0} &\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{s=1}^{S} \left(y_{i,s}-a_{i}\right)x_{i} + \sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{s=1}^{S}b_{j}z_{j,s} \\
&\text{s.t} \hspace{5pt} d_{ij}(c_{i}+y_{i,s}) \leq z_{j,s}^{1-\delta} \hspace{5pt} \forall \hspace{5pt}i,j,s
\end{align}

The problematic terms are the $y_{i,s}x_{i}$ which are bilinear functions. Are there any ways to either convexify this problem or provide a convex relaxation of this inner product?

Comment: I am sorry. Those were typos. Corrected!

Comment: If $\sum_s (y_{i,s}-a_i) \ge 0$, take $x_i=0$.  If $\sum_s (y_{i,s}-a_i) < 0$, the problem is unbounded because you can make $x_i$ arbitrarily large.

Comment: I see, you are right. This is clearly ill-posed. Thank you